# Prove that a proof system is not complete

Tags: database, database-design, logic, logical-operators, functional-dependencies

I want to prove that the proof system A is not complete.
A consists of these axioms:

```
1. Y subset or equal X => X->Y
2. X->Y and Y->Z   =>  X->Z (Transitive relation)
```

Therefore, I thought that I needed to prove that the axiom: X->Y => XZ->YZ cannot be proven using the axioms above.
I thought about proving this using induction but I'm not sure how.

I could say that the base is: X->Y therefore XZ->YZ cannot be proven.
But what about the rest?

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/ seems like a better fit for this question ???

Answer (score 1):

You want to prove that A is not complete with respect to what?

The rule X->Y => XZ->YZ can be proved using the proof system A. You go by induction with respect to size of the proof of X->Y.

- Base case: if X->Y follows from 1. then XZ->YZ follows from 1 (YZ is a subset of XZ).
- Step: if X->Y follows from 2. with X->B, B->Y as premises, then XZ->BZ and BZ->YZ follow from the induction step. The apply rule 2. again and you get XZ->YZ. QED